# Trouble calling external JAX-RS service from within JBoss application

Tags: jboss, maven-2, client, jax-rs, resteasy

I am having a lot of issues with something I thought should be easy:
From my J2E web application (Stateless session bean), I want to call an external JAX-RS service (mailgun).
I tried integrating Jersey but had issues with overlapping imports (and NoSuchMethodExceptions etc.). So I did not pursue this further and tried RestEasy instead, as I understood that this is Jboss's standard JAX-RS library.

However, I am running into issues here as well.

Can you please point me to the correct path of invoking these services? I am very open using any library, so if there is a "build-in" way of doing this, I am happy to let go on my dependency hell here...

Details of my current issues:

Once I am invoking this line from my StatelessSessionBean:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response res = client.target("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org" +   "/messages").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).get();
```

Already the first line produces an Exception:

```
    JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component EmailService for method public void de.wohnungsheld.weimea.service.EmailService.hasso(): javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder
```

I played a lot with my Maven dependencies.
The current version references (amongst others)

```
 jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec
```

and

```
 org.jboss.resteasy, version 3.0.8.Final
```

I assume that org.jboss.resteasy collides with something else here...

The complete dependencies section looks like this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
        typesafe criteria queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
        annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->

    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
          <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openestate.is24</groupId>
        <artifactId>ALL</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
        <artifactId>picketlink</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
          <type>pom</type>                             
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Dependency management looks like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>${version.picketlink.javaee.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I am running JBoss AS 7.1.

Many thanks in advance!

PS: I am exposing a lot of JAX-RS services from my application, which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "Why am I getting NoClassDefFoundError," the answer is "Because the dependency org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs is marked as provided and therefore not available at runtime."

Note that JBoss AS 7.1 does NOT use the version 3.0.8 of Reasteasy (In your case, probably Resteasy 2.3.5, but I don't know what is the value of ${version.jboss.bom} you use; check the value of ${version.org.jboss.resteasy})

Consider adding the dependency jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy to your pom, or use using jboss-javaee-6.0-with-all, so you don't need to set the version of Resteasy yourself.

If you want to update the version of Resteasy used in JBoss, see http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.8.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#upgrading-as7

If it is an option, you can also use WildFly, which supports Resteasy 3.0.6 out of box.